# how to hide photos from gallery in flutter

Tags: flutter, show-hide, delete-file

```
final ImagePicker imagePicker = ImagePicker();

try {
  if(await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
    final List<XFile> pickedImages = await imagePicker.pickMultiImage();
    print(pickedImages.length);
    
    for(int i=0; i<pickedImages.length; i++) {
      
      final String newPath = "${directory!.path}${pickedImages[i].name}";

      final File pickedImage = File(pickedImages[i].path);
      await pickedImage.copy(newPath);
      images.add(newPath);

      await calLockDB!.rawInsert("INSERT INTO photos_info (saved_path) VALUES('$newPath');");
      // oldImageDirectory.delete();
      
      print("Old Image Name : ${pickedImages[i].name}");
      print("New Path : $newPath");
    }
    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PhotosPage()));
  }
} catch (e) {
  mySnackBar(context, color: Colors.red, message: "Something went wrong!.");
  print(e);
}
```

I am developing an flutter application where it will select some photos from the gallery and hide them,

but i can't delete/hide photos from gallery.

i gets cache picture path by image_picker library, but i want original path to delete or hide the picture.

so how can i delete/ hide picture from gallery in flutter ?

Answer (score 0):

use photo_manager library, that provides actuall path of images and videos of local device.

https://pub.dev/packages?q=photo+manager